# I'm not really [content] with this tag

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [content](/questions/tagged/content) tag has 34 questions but no usage guidance, and it seems to be used for many types of content: user generated content (in the form of questions, answers or tag wikis) but also content owned by the company (e.g. Help Center articles). Sometimes it's about technical aspects of content, sometimes the opposite. What should we do with this tag? Burninate it, or find one clear, unambiguous purpose for it, document that in the excerpt and remove it from questions where it does not apply?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Yes, it's a meta tag.

Comment: And plagiarism, the Contact Us page, etc. etc.  I find that a lot of questions talking about the content of a question or answer can do with the [editor] tag; we've already got [inappropriate-content] for... inappropriate content.  Overall, I'm [content] with living without this tag.  Let's burn it.